# content type is different in response

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am reading a binary file and trying to send in body of a response with application/octet-stream as content type. In postman and chrome I could get the binary data in the body but the headers are still application/json no matter what I change/do.

edit:

```
desc 'Retrieve a Binary file' do
            detail 'Retrieves a binary for a given file.'
            produces ['application/octet-stream','application/json',
                      'application/xml', 'text/plain']

          get tags: ['abc'] do
            content_type 'application/octet-stream'
            present stubed_data
          end
```

and api.rb has

```
    content_type :xml, 'application/xml'
    content_type :json, 'application/json'
    content_type :binary, 'application/octet-stream'
    content_type :txt, 'text/plain'
    default_format :json
```

Comment: Can you show your setup?

Comment: @EJ2015 Thanks for your response. Please look at my edit.

Comment: Did you try setting the Accept header in your request?

Comment: Yes. Even tried with content-type in request header too. No luck!